# jwplayer convert <object> to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I am trying to convert the code below:

```
<object data="http://www.primcast.com/jwplayer5/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
 <param name="quality" value="high">
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
 <param name="flashvars" id="flashvars" value="
   &amp;file=MarinaFM2
   &amp;streamer=rtmp://38.96.175.16:1935/live
   &amp;autostart=false
   &amp;stretching=uniform
 ">
</object>
```

to this code:

```
<head>
 <script src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="mediaplayer"></div>
 <script>
  jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
   file: "MarinaFM2",
   streamer: "rtmp://38.96.175.16:1935/live",
   autostart: false,
   stretching: "uniform"
  });
 </script>
</body>
```

but I get "Error loading player: No playable sources found"

can anyone try it and give me the solution thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
file: "MarinaFM2",
streamer: "rtmp://38.96.175.16:1935/live",
```

Needs to be:

```
file: "rtmp://38.96.175.16:1935/live/MarinaFM2",
```

Comment: This solution did not work and I get the same error "Error loading player: No playable sources found"

Comment: Do you have a link? I just tested in our wizard, http://www.jwplayer.com/wizard/, using this as the file, rtmp://38.96.175.16:1935/live/MarinaFM2, and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes it work in your wizard but not in my code? and I have local jwplayer, I also test it with some local mp3 files and it's work fine. does I missing something in my code or there is something wrong I dont understand!

Comment: Are you running on a local web server?  Or on a local C drive?

Comment: I am running on a local C drive

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working page that you can run in your localhost or web server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RTMP Stream</title>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mediaplayer"></div>
 <script>
  jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
   file: "rtmp://38.96.175.16:1935/live/MarinaFM2",
   autostart: false,
   stretching: "uniform"
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code give me this error "Error loading player: could not load player configuration"